# Dividir valores de un diccionario entre constante

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo un diccionario tal como este:

```
{'college': 13656,
 'high school': 4906,
 'less than high school': 2904,
 'more than high school but not college': 6999}
```

Me gustaría saber como se podría dividir los valores del diccionario por una constante (en mi caso particular, es por la longitud de un dataframe (len(df)).

Como la len(df) = 28465. La solución es la siguiente:

```
{'college': 0.47974705779026877,
 'high school': 0.172352011241876,
 'less than high school': 0.10202002459160373,
 'more than high school but not college': 0.24588090637625154}
```

Como se pueden dividir directamente los valores?

Yo lo he hecho sacando los keys e introduciendolos en una lista (l1), luego he sacado los values y los he introducido en una lista (l2) que he dividido por la constante y al final he aplicado un dict(zip(l1, l2). Consigo el resultado pero el procedimiento me parece terrible.

Cuál sería una solución mas óptima?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe la compresión de diccionarios, al igual que la compresión de listas:

```
costs = {'college': 13656,
 'high school': 4906,
 'less than high school': 2904,
 'more than high school but not college': 6999}

costs = {key: value /  28465 for key, value in costs.items()}
```

¿Cómo funciona? `costs` es un diccionario y `costs.items()` devuelve sus componentes en pares que aqui llamamos `key` y `value` (los nombres son arbitrarios).

Teniendo key y value, defino una entrada asi:

```
key: value / 28465
```

**Demo**

```
costs = {'college': 13656,
 'high school': 4906,
 'less than high school': 2904,
 'more than high school but not college': 6999}

costs = {key: value /  28465 for key, value in costs.items()}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(costs)
```

produce:

```
{'college': 0.47974705779026877,
 'high school': 0.172352011241876,
 'less than high school': 0.10202002459160373,
 'more than high school but not college': 0.24588090637625154}
```

Comment: Eres un genio, te casarás con quien quieras. Gracias de nuevo!

Answer (score 1):

¿Algo así te refieres?

```
d = {'college': 13656,
 'high school': 4906,
 'less than high school': 2904,
 'more than high school but not college': 6999}

constante = 28465

nuevo_d = {key: value/constante for key, value in d.items()}

print(nuevo_d)
```

Devuelve:

```
{'college': 0.47974705779026877, 'high school': 0.172352011241876, 'less than high school': 0.10202002459160373, 'more than high school but not college': 0.24588090637625154}
```

Answer (score 1):

A veces los pythonistas nos complicamos innecesariamente la vida con `zip()`, comprensiones y otras posibilidades que el lenguaje nos ofrece, y que son muy útiles y válidas en muchos escenarios. Pero en este caso particular creo que un vulgar `for` resuelve el problema de forma mucho más eficiente, debido a que modifica el diccionario "en el sitio" sin necesidad de crear diccionarios intermedios y por tanto sin molestar al recolector de basura.

```
d = {'college': 13656,
 'high school': 4906,
 'less than high school': 2904,
 'more than high school but not college': 6999}

for k in d:
  d[k] /= 28465
print(d)
```

---

```
{'college': 0.47974705779026877,
 'high school': 0.172352011241876,
 'less than high school': 0.10202002459160373,
 'more than high school but not college': 0.24588090637625154}}
```

Siempre, claro está, que sea aceptable para ti que `d` quede modificado. Si quieres preservar el `d` original y crear un diccionario nuevo con el resultado, entonces una comprensión de diccionarios como la mostrada en las otras respuestas sería perfecta.

Comment: Primera vez que te veo escribir un `for`

Comment: @CandidMoe A veces un `for` es preferible. No siempre una comprensión es más eficiente. He cronometrado tiempos y este for es más rápido que crear un diccionario nuevo. Supongo que básicamente se debe a la modificación "in place", que es realizada por una sola operación en bytecode, y al evitar llamadas a métodos como `.items()`. Las iteraciones en sí cuestan lo mismo. Lo que se suele ganar al usar una comprensión es que te evitas el `list.append()` (o `dict.update()`) pero en este caso no hace falta de eso.